# Customize title of listofschemes

Tags: chemstyle

While trying to customize the title that is printed by the command `\listofschemes` of the `chemstyle` package, I have encountered an unexpected behaviour.

To quote from the `chemstyle` manual:

> To match the \listoffigures and \listoftables macros provided by the
>   LaTeX kernel, chemscheme provides a \listofschemes command. This works
>   in the same way as the kernel commands, with the default text stored
>   in the macro \listschemename.

In order to overwrite the default title of the list of figures, I usually use the following command in the preamble of my documents:

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\listfigurename{Verzeichnis der Abbildungen}}
```

While this command works as expected, the analogous command to change the title of the list of schemes, has no effect when using `ngerman` as the language specification. (As shown in the following MWE). If one changes `ngerman` to `english` the expected output is enerated.

Is there any possibility to overcome this?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\listschemename{Verzeichnis der Schemata}}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\listfigurename{Verzeichnis der Abbildungen}}

\begin{document}

\listofschemes
\listoffigures

\begin{scheme}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
\end{scheme}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chemscheme` package, which is responsible for the `\listofschemes` command adds its own translation for `\listschemename` at begin document, so your `\addto` command appears too early and is overridden.

However, it's not sufficient to delay it with `\AtBeginDocument`, because `chemscheme` also performs `\selectlanguage{\languagename}`.

Solution: execute also `\csname captions\languagename\endcsname`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\listfigurename{Verzeichnis der Abbildungen}}
  \addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\listschemename{Verzeichnis der Schemata}}%
  \csname captions\languagename\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

\listofschemes
\listoffigures

\begin{scheme}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
\caption{What's up, doc?}
\end{scheme}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
\caption{What's up, doc?}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The first `\addto` instruction could be outside `\AtBeginDocument`, but it's more consistent to keep all of them together.

[image]